# Make Applescript wait for an application to be closed before running a shell script

Tags: macos, shell, shell-script, applescript, applet

I have an applet i made using Applescript which opens an Application and then once it's loaded runs a shell script which unload's Spotlight. I need to make it then wait for me to finish using relevant Application before running another shell script to load Spotlight again.

My code currently looks like:

```
set appname to “Applications/Cubase 5.app”
    tell application appname to launch
        repeat until application appname is running    
        delay 1
        end repeat
if application appname is running then
    do shell script "sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist" password "YOUR_PASSWORD" with administrator privileges
    end if
activate appname
```

I have tried everything but can not figure it out. I found and modified this script with my limited knowledge but do not understand how it works

What code do i need to add to make it wait for me to then quit the application to run the second shell script which i know is:

```
do shell script "sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist" password "YOUR_PASSWORD" with administrator privileges
```

which **would** reload Spotlight?

I came with up the following which compiles but doesn't do as expected:

```
set appname to “Applications/Cubase 5.app”
    tell application appname to launch
        repeat until application appname is running    
        delay 1
        end repeat
if application appname is running then
    do shell script "sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist" password "YOUR_PASSWORD" with administrator privileges
    end if
activate appname
    repeat until application appname is not running
    delay 1
    end repeat
if application is not running then
    do shell script "sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist" password "YOUR_PASSWORD" with administrator privileges
end if
```

Gives me the error *Can't get running of application*. I can see something is missing just do not know what.

I'm new to both Apple and Applescript and an answer will be much appreciated.

Comment: @Danny - I wrote the above code with your suggestion of inserting the ***not*** but it doesn't do as expected as explained in my re-edited question above. I hope my edit helps explain my question better. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

you want to test for ***not*** running

```
set appname to “Applications/Cubase 5.app”
    tell application appname to launch
        repeat until application appname is not running    
            delay 1
        end repeat
if application appname is running then
    do shell script "sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist" password "YOUR_PASSWORD" with administrator privileges
end if
activate appname
```

Comment: Perhaps my question was ambiguous. I want to add something to the existing script, so that once I'm done using the Application and i close it, another shell script is run. Basically, I want to run Cubase 5, then unload Spotlight, then once i'm done working in Cubase and quit, have the script load spotlight again. Hope that clarifies.Thanks for the response @Danny

Comment: @Ambush - look carefully - I added ONE word to your existing script and now it should behave as you explain. appname is _not_ running

Comment: I saw that you added the _not_ but i don't understand how that will make the script perform all 3 actions? Shouldn't I be adding more code somewhere?